# Is it true that cats themselves are not smelly?

Tags: cats

I heard some theories that normal cats are not smelly, and odor is caused by some abnormal conditions such as illness, lack bathing or lack house cleaning, is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Cats keep themselves quite clean, so that even an "alley cat" will not be smelly. If a cat stops cleaning itself, that is normally a sign of illness, or a physical problem that makes it difficult for the cat to bathe itself (for example, the cat may be severely overweight, which makes it less limber).

Comment: A friend of mine named her childhood cat "talcum powder" because that's what she thought he smelled like. Having had my face buried in my own cats' fur, I think she has a point... Healthy cats are a lot less smelly than most dogs and some people.